# Get Full Months and the Remaining as Days in Joda Time

Tags: scala, jodatime

I have the following code snippet with which I'm trying to get the total months that are in between a certain date and the remaining as the number of days.

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Days, Interval, Weeks, Months}
import scala.math.Integral.Implicits._

val start = new DateTime(2022, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
val end = new DateTime(2022, 4, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0)
val days = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays + 1
val monthss = Months.monthsBetween(start, end)
val months = Math.abs(monthss.getMonths())
val (monate, remaining)= days /% 30

println(days)
println(monate)
println(remaining)
```

As it can be seen that it prints the following:

```
61
2
1
```

Which is wrong. I know where the mistake is. As I'm always taking 30 as the mod, it gives me a remaining number of days as 1, but here I expect that it is a full 2 month period with a remaining day of 0.

Any ideas as to how to get it correct?

Comment: Create a Joda-Time `Period` using `new Period(start, end, PeriodType.yearMonthDay())` and get the months and days from its `getMonths` and its `getDays` methods. In your example case you get 1 month and 29 days. If years may be non-zero, need to take this into account separately. May first add 1 day to `end` if you want it included in the count. May also consider switching to java.time.

Comment: Let me add: to get the total number of months also when they are more than 12, use `p.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.months()).getMonths()` where `p` is your `Period`.